# May std::map key address number of values?

Tags: c++

It may be a little bit stupid question, but assuming the `std::map` defined as follows:

```
 std::map<int, int> m;
```

Is there any way to have more than one value stored and be accessible for a single `key`?

**Motivation of asking:**

`std::map` has methods like `count()` and `equal_range()` that get a key as parameters, that kind of give a sense that there is more than one value may be specified by a single key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those methods exist so as to provide a *common interface* with other associative containers that do allow multiple values per key (such as [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) which is exactly what you're looking for).

This makes implementing algorithms generically (i.e. with templates) much easier than it would otherwise be, and nothing of value is lost by designing it this way.

It's true that, in the case of [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), `count()` can only give you zero or one (unless you're using transparent keys, which are a whole other kettle of fish).

C++20 will introduce [`std::map::contains()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/contains), which is more or less a check that `count() == 1` — this seems to have been intended to address concerns that the function `count()` is kind of a weird thing to have for a `std::map` specifically.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to have more than one value stored and be accessible for a single `key`?

Not with `std::map`, these objects store only one value per key, but [`std::multimap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) can store a variable number of values per key.

Similarities between both types (e.g. `std::map::count`, `std::multimap::count`) are due to establishing similar interfaces between STL containers.

Answer (score 1):

No. `std::map` is designed to have one value per key. 
If you want multiple values for one key, you should use `std::multimap`.